# How to make setWindowIcon work properly in a stand-alone executable (Qt5.14 + VS2019)?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2019, application-icon

I am programming a Qt application in MS Visual Studio Community 2019. I am trying to add an icon to my application window with the following command, and I also have the corresponding file **my_icon.ico** mentioned in the **.qrc** file:

```
setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/my_icon.ico"));
```

When I build and run my program in VS, everything is perfect - the icon replaces the standard one. However, when I make a release and try to run the resulting stand-alone executable, the icon is NOT shown! This is particularly weird as images which I also mention in the **.qrc** file (pictures for buttons) are on their places.

I have tried to put **my_icon.ico** alongside the **.exe** file, but with no result.

I give up, please give me a clue what might be happening here.

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Please use windeployqt - then the plugin for the ico image format is properly copied to the correct location and the image can be loaded.

Comment: It turns out I am pretty new in this, as before I programmed only rather simple console soft. What I do now is I just build a release version in Visual Stidio, then I go to the Release directory and I copy the .exe file to a fresh folder. Surely it was annoyed by the absence of Qt libraries which I gave to it manually by copy&paste from Qt folder.

Comment: Could you clarify where should windeployqt enter this pipeline? As far as I got from this documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html), I should configure the whole Qt to be static (as my dream is to have all libraries inside my .exe) and then feed the Release folder to windeployqt program. Am I right or do I miss something important?

Comment: How do you currently deploy your app? Simply by copying the exectuables + dlls? Don't do this but use windeployqt as described in the documentation. I would not use static linking in this early stage of knowledge. Esp. since it does not give you much - creating a proper installer is the much better way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [chehrlic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13043272/chehrlic), I understood that it was as simple as running the **windeployqt.exe** on the **.exe** file build by the Release configuration by Visual Studio.

This will link all required libraries dynamically.

Avoid using this tool while the **.exe** file is inside the Release folder as it will create many other files & folders near **.exe** file. I have copied **my_app.exe** to a fresh directory and ran the following command from it:

```
C:\Qt\5.14.1\msvc2017_64\bin\windeployqt.exe my_app.exe --release
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html for more details.